# How to create a for loop over files in Makefile that works in Linux and Windows?

Tags: for-loop, makefile, cross-platform

### What I have

I have a Makefile that loops through subdirectories and runs a command.
I'm trying to make this work both in Linux and Windows, but getting a `CreateProcess(NULL, ifdef OS, ...) failed` message when trying to run it.

```
something:
    for fn in ./{*/some.file}; do
        cd $${name} && echo $${name};
    done
```

### What I've tried

```
something:
    ifdef OS
        for fn in $(subdirs); do \
            cd $$fn && @echo $$fn;
        done
    else
        for fn in ./{*/some.file}; do
            cd $${name} && echo $${name};
        done
    endif
```

This doesn't satisfy the requirement of finding all instances of `some.file` though.

### What I'm trying to do

1. Loop over all subdirectories that have file `some.file`
2. Change directory and run a command

Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

What I'm trying to accomplish here is some dev automation for serverless. The subdirectories contain code in several programming languages and logic is ran specific to the setup. For example `some.file` may refer to `package.json` and run an `npm` command, or maybe it's python, or go, or rust, etc. This would give me flexibility to work with multiple languages on multiple OS and automate specific repetitive tasks like installation of packages, building, testing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best/most portable way to handle this is not to use loops at all.  Let make handle it for you.  For example you can write a make rule that handles one subdirectory, then create a rule with prerequisites for each directory you want to work with:

```
SUBDIRS = this that other
.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)

something: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS): %:
        cd $@ && echo $@
```